# BeautifulSoup problem using 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup' not working on Python 3.7 with mac

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I installed BeautifulSoup with my terminal, and when i got to Python 3.7.0 shell i cannot import using 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup'

like this:

```
> >> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
>     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Please help!

Comment: How did you install beautifulsoup? Perhaps try again, making sure it's a Python 3.x variant

Comment: make sure you use pip3 to install it.

Comment: `pip3 install beautifulsoup4` should do it

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the global Python3 that's installed on the whole mac operating system, you can see which libraries you have currently installed by running pip3 freeze:

```
> pip3 freeze
certifi==2018.4.16
....
```

Then install beautifulsoup4 and verify your new library is available again with pip3 freeze:

```
> pip3 install beautifulsoup4
> pip3 freeze                
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3
certifi==2018.4.16
```